# {If $\frac{1+4p}{p},\frac{1-p}{4},\frac{1-2p}{2} $ are probabilities of$ 3$ mutually exclusive events.

Tags: probability

> If  $\frac{1+4p}{p},\frac{1-p}{4},\frac{1-2p}{2} $ are probabilies of $ 3$ mutually exclusive events. Then,

$$1) p=1/2$$

$$2) p=3/4$$

$$3) p=1/3$$

$$4) none of these$$

My Approach:

A=(1+4p)/p,

B=(1-p)/4,

C=(1-2p)/2

For Mutually Exclusive Events, (A intersection B intersection C)=0

Then, (1+4p)/p,(1-p)/4,(1-2p)/2 all  lies between 0 to 1.

p(A)=(1+4p)/p=0<=(1+4p/p)<=1

p(B)=(1-p)/4=0<=(1-p)/4<=1

p(C)=(1-2p)/2=0<=(1-2p)/2<=1

Solving these i got from A

-3/4<=p<=-1/4  @Edit

Solving these i got from B

-3<=p<=1   @Edit

Solving these i got from C

-1/2<=p<=1/2

p(A union B union C)=Sample space

0<=(1+4p)/p+(1-p)/4+(1-2p)/2<=1

Solving these by taking L.C.M i get 2 equations 5p2-19p-4>=0 and 5p2-23p-4<=0

Thus,I am stuck here and hence could not solve from here.

Comment: $\dfrac{1+4p}{p}$, $\dfrac{1-p}{4}$ and $\dfrac{1-2p}{2}$ or something else?

Comment: @Henry What do you mean by something else Sir

Comment: " $ 1+4p/p,1-p/4,1-2p/2$ " could mean a lot of different things.  Most mathematicians do division before addition or subtraction

Comment: @Henry Done editing Is it Fine?

Comment: Better, though [MathJax/$\TeX$](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) would be best

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: What about $P(A\cup B)$? $P(A\cup C)$? $P(B\cup C)$? $P(A\cup B\cup C)$?

Also, how did you get from $B$ to $-1\leq p\leq 1$? Can you write down your calculation?

Comment: It should be equal to sample space i got ur hint add all 3 probability which also lies between 0 to 1 and also Sir it should be -3<=p<=1.

Comment: @justintakro $-3\leq p\leq 1$ is correct. But for $A$, the solution is not correct.

Comment: Is it correct now?What value u got for p after that i am solving the last equation.

Comment: I didn't got the last equation.